# Embedded Java Database with Restore Point and Flashback system

Tags: java, oracle, h2, derby, embedded-database

I'm looking for a java embedded database that having functionality for doing something similar to undo-redo like create restore point / flashback on Oracle Database.

I want to create a restore point and come back to this point with incremental system without loading or reloading all the database from a backup.
Do you know if embedded database like h2, derby or other have this kind of possibilities ?

Oracle documentation about kind of thing : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/rpfbdb002.htm

Answer (score 1):

Derby provides a way to take backups, and restore those backups. But the Derby backup and restore functionality does copy all the data in the database during those operations. So for Derby I believe the answer is: "no, Derby does not provide flashback features like Oracle does".